# Parse a string in C89/C90

Tags: c, string, parsing, scanf, c89

I'm parsing a string into variables and I almost have what I want.

The string to be parsed looks like this

```
char [128] = "D4 E 3 NullByte Sub";
```

Now I would like to split this into 4 variables:

- **D4** would be the location
- **E** would be the direction
- **3** would be the length
- **NullByte Sub** is the name.

So far I've been using `sscanf` for splitting into variables using the code below (assume that the variables are already created):

```
sscanf(line, "%s %s %d %s", location, direction, &length, name);
```

So this scans location, direction and length correctly but chops off the `Sub` part of name.

I want to know how to ignore any other spaces and read what ever is left into name. No matter the number of spaces etc.

So if

```
line = "D4 E 3 NullByte Sub Ship Barrier"
```

Then I could expect the name to be

```
"NullByte Sub Ship Barrier"
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
int offset;
sscanf(line, "%s %s %d %n", location, direction, &length, &offset);
name = line + offset; // or strncpy or something, if you want a new string instead of just a pointer into the old one
```

`%n` records how many characters have been consumed so far. If you jump forward that many characters, then you get the rest of the string.

Side note: using `%s` without a maximum field width (or letting it allocate itself with the `m` modifier) is dangerous unless you're 100% sure that you'll never get an overly-long word.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `%s` format for [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (and related function like `sscanf`) reads a *space-delimited* string.

Since there's no good "end of record" marker in the string (beyond the actual end of the string) it's hard to use `sscanf` at all, even with its special `%[` format specifier.

Instead I suggest you learn about [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) and how to use it to "tokenize" a string.

With it you could do something like:

```
char *p = strtok(line, " ");
strcpy(location, p);

p = strtok(NULL, " ");
strcpy(direction, p);

p = strtok(NULL, " ");
length = strtol(p, NULL, 10);

strcpy(name, p + strlen(p) + 1);  // p + strlen(p) skips over the number, +1 to skip over the space as well
```

Comment: Now that I really thought about this, `p + strlen(p) + 1` is right, but it looks SUPER sketchy.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use the `sscanf` character class *format-specifier* `"%[^\n]"` to read the name, e.g.

```
    if (sscanf (str, "%7s %7s %d %63[^\n]", loc, dir, &len, name))
        printf ("loc : %s\ndir : %s\nlen : %d\nname: %s\n", loc, dir, len, name);
```

The *field-width* modifier must be used with any string conversion or `sscanf` is no better than `gets()`. The widths would correspond to the following declarations, e.g.

```
    char str[] = "D4 E 3 NullByte Sub", 
        loc[8], dir[8], name[64];
    int len;
```

A complete example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char str[] = "D4 E 3 NullByte Sub", 
        str2[] = "D4 E 3 NullByte Sub Ship Barrier",
        loc[8], dir[8], name[64];
    int len;

    if (sscanf (str, "%7s %7s %d %63[^\n]", loc, dir, &len, name))
        printf ("\nloc : %s\ndir : %s\nlen : %d\nname: %s\n", loc, dir, len, name);

    if (sscanf (str2, "%7s %7s %d %63[^\n]", loc, dir, &len, name))
        printf ("\nloc : %s\ndir : %s\nlen : %d\nname: %s\n", loc, dir, len, name);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sscanf_loc-dir-name

loc : D4
dir : E
len : 3
name: NullByte Sub

loc : D4
dir : E
len : 3
name: NullByte Sub Ship Barrier
```

Comment: You're assuming that there will never be a newline in the name, but there's nothing in the question to back that assumption up.

Comment: You are entirely correct -- that is an assumption I have made and it is entirely backed up by `char [128] = "D4 E 3 NullByte Sub";` and `line = "D4 E 3 NullByte Sub Ship Barrier"` - neither of which can contain an embedded `'\n'` as written.